# C macro concatenation

Tags: c, macros

I'm trying to write simplest log_debug macro:

`#define log_debug(fmt, ...) printf("%s:%d "##fmt, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__);`

main reason is to get line number and file name. But somehow it does not work (compilation error):

`error: pasting ""%s:%d "" and ""error value: %d\n"" does not give a valid preprocessing token`

can you give me a clue is there any other way to rewrite it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, in C, adjacent string literals are joined automatically. How about

```
#define log_debug(fmt, ...) printf("%s:%d " fmt, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
                                           ^^ '##' removed
```

Comment: Well, they *are* the right solution if you want the correct `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` values. There's no other nice way to do it without a macro somewhere.

Comment: @H2CO3, macros are exactly what is foreseen by the C standard for these kind of things. That's why `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are expanded in the preprocessing phases.

Answer (score 3):

The error is because the concatenation would produce:

```
 "%s:%d""error value: %d\n"
```

Which is two tokens, rather than the single token the concatenation is expecting.

You actually don't need the `##` in this case, since consecutive string literals are implicitly joined:

```
... printf("%s:%d " fmt,  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should try something like

```
#define log_debug_(FILE, LINE, fmt, ...) printf(FILE ":" #LINE ": " fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
#define log_debug(fmt, ...) log_debug_(__FILE__, __LINE__, fmt, ...)
```

as effect this just prefixes your format string with another string that can be determined at compile time.